# sql pivot multiple and partially similar row values into multiple unknown number of cols

Tags: sql, oracle

To [SELECT multiple CASE-WHEN expressions into a single row per ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75058071/select-multiple-case-when-expressions-into-a-single-row-per-id) I have used aggregation `MAX` and `GROUPBY`.

```
SELECT table1.IDvar,
       MAX(CASE WHEN table2.var1 = 'foo' THEN table2.var2 END) AS condition1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN table2.var1 = 'bar' THEN table2.var2 END) AS condition2
FROM table1
FULL JOIN table2 ON table1.IDvar = table2.table1_IDvar
GROUP BY table1.IDvar
```

However, I have observed that empirical criteria such as `foo` entered in the CASE-WHEN-THEN-END expression may occur multiple times, that is, in multiple rows each of which corresponds to different values on columns of interest (`THEN column-of-interest END`)  in the db schema. This implies that taking the `MAX` or `MIN` drops data that may be of interest. It is not known in advance how many rows there are for each value in criteria_col and thus in the cols_of_interest.

Sample data e.g.:

| IDvar_foreign_key | criteria_col | col_of_interest1 | col_of_interest2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | foo | 01-01-2021 | 100 |
| x1 | foo | 01-06-2021 | 2000 |
| x1 | foo | 01-08-2021 | 0 |
| x1 | bar | 01-08-2021 | 300 |

*Note*: the actual table does contain a unique identifier or primary key.

Q: Are there ways to pivot certain columns/tables in a db schema without possibly dropping some values?

An ouput something like this:

| IDvar_foreign_key | foo_1_col_of_interest1 | foo_1_col_of_interest2 | foo_2_col_of_interest1 | foo_2_col_of_interest2 | foo_3_col_of_interest1 | foo_3_col_of_interest2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x1 | 01-01-2021 | 100 | 01-06-2021 | 2000 | 01-08-2021 | 0 |

**Edit**
@lemon and @MTO suggests dynamic queries are necesarry, otherwise I was considering whether not using aggregation would do

[Dynamic Pivot in Oracle's SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491661/1509264)

[Pivot rows to columns without aggregate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15674373/pivot-rows-to-columns-without-aggregate)

[TSQL Pivot without aggregate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343145/tsql-pivot-without-aggregate-function)

Comment: You need to also include the sample data in this question.  It is not acceptable/a complete question to refer to some other question and assume we have that background.

Comment: Do you know in advance how many records you may have in advance at max, for every unique <idvar, criteria>?

Comment: @lemon the number of records that should be pivotted is initially unknown. I can inspect it to be able to answer, but the content of the table may change. So I don't know how to specify systematically how many rows that have the same value in the criteria col that must be turned into cols.,

Comment: If you can't know in advance how many records at max you can have, you can't know how many columns your final table will have, hence you'd be in need of a dynamic query, which is much more expensive than a non-dynamic one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `MIN` and `MAX` aggregation functions and to get the correlated minimums and maximums for `col_of_interest2` you can use `KEEP (DENSE_RANK ...)`:

```
SELECT t1.IDvar,
       MIN(CASE WHEN t2.criteria_col = 'foo' THEN t2.col_of_interest1 END)
         AS foo_1_col_of_interest1,
       MIN(col_of_interest2) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY
         CASE WHEN t2.criteria_col = 'foo' THEN t2.col_of_interest1 END
         ASC NULLS LAST
       ) AS foo_1_col_of_interest2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN t2.criteria_col = 'foo' THEN t2.col_of_interest1 END)
         AS foo_2_col_of_interest1,
       MAX(col_of_interest2) KEEP (
         DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY
         CASE WHEN t2.criteria_col = 'foo' THEN t2.col_of_interest1 END
         DESC NULLS LAST
       ) AS foo_2_col_of_interest2
FROM   table1 t1
       FULL JOIN table2 t2
       ON t1.IDvar = t2.table1_IDvar
GROUP BY t1.IDvar
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 ( idvar ) AS
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 ( table1_idvar, criteria_col, col_of_interest1, col_of_interest2 ) AS
SELECT 1, 'foo', DATE '2021-01-01',  100 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'foo', DATE '2021-03-01',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'foo', DATE '2021-06-01', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'bar', DATE '2021-06-01', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'foo', DATE '2021-01-02',  200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'foo', DATE '2021-03-02',  300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'bar', DATE '2021-06-02',  400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'foo', DATE '2021-01-03',  700 FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| IDVAR | FOO_1_COL_OF_INTEREST1 | FOO_1_COL_OF_INTEREST2 | FOO_2_COL_OF_INTEREST1 | FOO_2_COL_OF_INTEREST2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 100 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 2000 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 200 | 2021-03-02 00:00:00 | 300 |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 700 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 700 |

---

SQL (not just Oracle) requires each query to have a known, fixed number of columns; if you want a dynamic number of columns then you should perform the pivot in whatever third-party application (Java, C#, PHP, etc.) that you are using to talk to the database.

If you want to pivot a fixed maximum number of columns then you can use the `ROW_NUMBER` analytic function. For example, if you want the 3 minimum values for `col_of_interest1` then you can use:

```sql
SELECT idvar,
       MAX(CASE WHEN criteria_col = 'foo' AND rn = 1 THEN col_of_interest1 END)
         AS foo_1_col_of_interest1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN criteria_col = 'foo' AND rn = 1 THEN col_of_interest2 END)
         AS foo_1_col_of_interest2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN criteria_col = 'foo' AND rn = 2 THEN col_of_interest1 END)
         AS foo_2_col_of_interest1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN criteria_col = 'foo' AND rn = 2 THEN col_of_interest2 END)
         AS foo_2_col_of_interest2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN criteria_col = 'foo' AND rn = 3 THEN col_of_interest1 END)
         AS foo_3_col_of_interest1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN criteria_col = 'foo' AND rn = 3 THEN col_of_interest2 END)
         AS foo_3_col_of_interest2
FROM   (
  SELECT t1.IDvar,
         criteria_col,
         col_of_interest1,
         col_of_interest2,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY t1.IDvar, criteria_col
           ORDER BY col_of_interest1, col_of_interest2
         ) AS rn
  FROM   table1 t1
         FULL JOIN table2 t2
         ON t1.IDvar = t2.table1_IDvar
  WHERE  criteria_col IN ('foo' /*, 'bar', 'etc'*/)
)
GROUP BY idvar
```

Which outputs:

| IDVAR | FOO_1_COL_OF_INTEREST1 | FOO_1_COL_OF_INTEREST2 | FOO_2_COL_OF_INTEREST1 | FOO_2_COL_OF_INTEREST2 | FOO_3_COL_OF_INTEREST1 | FOO_3_COL_OF_INTEREST2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 00:00:00 | 100 | 2021-03-01 00:00:00 | 500 | 2021-06-01 00:00:00 | 2000 |
| 2 | 2021-01-02 00:00:00 | 200 | 2021-03-02 00:00:00 | 300 | *null* | *null* |
| 3 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 700 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kt5EYSWJ)

Comment: Thanks for helping, MTO. I edited my question to indicate that I do not know in advance the number of records to be transposed/pivoted. This means that `MIN` and `MAX` aggregations catch some but not all values. Does that make sense? Would you edit your answer to take this into account?

Comment: And can you explain the concept 'correlated minimum and maximum'?

Comment: Regarding the correlation, consider [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/7yh1mRyd) where the values for `idVar = 1` the earliest `col_of_interest1` corresponds to the largest  `col_of_interest2` so you cannot take the minimum of both columns, you have to find the minimum date and then find the correlated `col_of_interest2` for that date.

Comment: @Johan_A Regarding the unknown number of values to pivot; SQL (not just Oracle) does not support that as an SQL statement **MUST** have a known, fixed number of columns. The normal solution is to pivot the table in whatever third-party application (Java, PHP, C#, etc.) that you are using to access the database. If you cannot do that then you would need to use dynamic SQL [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491661/1509264)

Comment: re correlation; so it means something like taking the value in another col on the same row as the value in the first col?

Comment: regarding unknown number of cols (from unkown number of row values). I dont understand how it can not be possible, while it can be possible using dynamic SQL. Can I put it this way: It is possible with a dynamic query?

Comment: @Johan_A Yes to both (however, dynamic SQL is difficult to use, write and maintain so it is generally not recommended; perform the pivot in Java/C#/PHP/etc. if you can).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see. And I see in your edited answer a possible way to account for multiple cols using ROW_NUMBER, however, knowing the number of rows/cols. I will explore dynamic queries, thanks again for the link you provided. As it stands, it seems my question cannot be answered without dynamic but unadvised queries. I will +1 to you however.

Answer (score 1):

Unknown number of columns is an issue that you can't ignore. The question is - are there any possible expected limits. I question who would get any meaningfull insight from a resulting dataset with hundreds of columns. It doesnt make sense. If you could setup the limit to 10 or 20 or whatever like that then you could build a datagrid structure using pivot where the number of columns would be the same and the data within could be placed as in your question.
Just as an example how  - here is the code that does it with up to 6 pairs of your data of interest (COL_DATE and COL_VALUE) - it could be 20 or 30 or ...

First your sample data and some preparation for pivoting (CTE named grid):

```sql
WITH    -- S a m p l e    d a t a
    tbl AS
        (
            SELECT 1 "ID", 'foo' "CRITERIA", DATE '2021-01-01' "INTEREST_1",  100 "INTEREST_2" FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1, 'foo', DATE '2021-03-01',  500 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1, 'foo', DATE '2021-06-01', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 1, 'bar', DATE '2021-06-01', 2000 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2, 'foo', DATE '2021-01-02',  200 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2, 'foo', DATE '2021-03-02',  300 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 2, 'bar', DATE '2021-06-02',  400 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
            SELECT 3, 'foo', DATE '2021-01-03',  700 FROM DUAL 
        ),
    grid AS
        (SELECT * FROM
            (  Select    ID "ID",  CRITERIA "GRP", INTEREST_1 "COL_DATE", INTEREST_2 "COL_VALUE", 
                        Count(*) OVER(Partition By ID, CRITERIA) "ROWS_TOT", 
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By ID, CRITERIA Order By ID, CRITERIA) "RN_GRP_ID",
                        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Partition By ID, CRITERIA Order By ID, CRITERIA) "RN_GRP_ID_2"
              From      tbl t )
         ORDER BY  ID ASC, GRP DESC, ROWS_TOT DESC
        ),
        
Result (grid)
        ID GRP COL_DATE   COL_VALUE   ROWS_TOT  RN_GRP_ID RN_GRP_ID_2
---------- --- --------- ---------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1 foo 01-JAN-21        100          3          3           3 
         1 foo 01-JUN-21       2000          3          2           2 
         1 foo 01-MAR-21        500          3          1           1 
         1 bar 01-JUN-21       2000          1          1           1 
         2 foo 02-MAR-21        300          2          2           2 
         2 foo 02-JAN-21        200          2          1           1 
         2 bar 02-JUN-21        400          1          1           1 
         3 foo 03-JAN-21        700          1          1           1
```

... next is pivoting (another CTE named grid_pivot) and designing another grid that will be populated with your data of interest...

```sql
    grid_pivot AS
        (   SELECT
                ID, GRP, ROWS_TOT, 
                MAX(GRP_1_LINK) "GRP_1_LINK", CAST(Null as DATE) "GRP_1_DATE", CAST(Null as NUMBER) "GRP_1_VALUE",
                MAX(GRP_2_LINK) "GRP_2_LINK", CAST(Null as DATE) "GRP_2_DATE", CAST(Null as NUMBER) "GRP_2_VALUE",
                MAX(GRP_3_LINK) "GRP_3_LINK", CAST(Null as DATE) "GRP_3_DATE", CAST(Null as NUMBER) "GRP_3_VALUE",
                MAX(GRP_4_LINK) "GRP_4_LINK", CAST(Null as DATE) "GRP_4_DATE", CAST(Null as NUMBER) "GRP_4_VALUE",
                MAX(GRP_5_LINK) "GRP_5_LINK", CAST(Null as DATE) "GRP_5_DATE", CAST(Null as NUMBER) "GRP_5_VALUE",
                MAX(GRP_6_LINK) "GRP_6_LINK", CAST(Null as DATE) "GRP_6_DATE", CAST(Null as NUMBER) "GRP_6_VALUE"
              --  ...  ... ... ...
            FROM
                (   Select  * 
                      From    ( Select * From grid )
                          PIVOT ( Max(RN_GRP_ID) "LINK"  --Min(RN_GRP_ID) "GRP_FROM", 
                                  FOR RN_GRP_ID_2 IN(1 "GRP_1", 2 "GRP_2", 3 "GRP_3", 4 "GRP_4", 5 "GRP_5", 6 "GRP_6" ) ) -- ...  ...
                      Order By ROWS_TOT DESC, GRP DESC, ID ASC
                )
            GROUP BY GRP, ROWS_TOT, ID
            ORDER BY ROWS_TOT DESC, GRP DESC, ID ASC
        )

Result (grid_pivot)
        ID GRP   ROWS_TOT GRP_1_LINK GRP_1_DATE GRP_1_VALUE GRP_2_LINK GRP_2_DATE GRP_2_VALUE GRP_3_LINK GRP_3_DATE GRP_3_VALUE GRP_4_LINK GRP_4_DATE GRP_4_VALUE GRP_5_LINK GRP_5_DATE GRP_5_VALUE GRP_6_LINK GRP_6_DATE GRP_6_VALUE
---------- --- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ---------- -----------
         1 foo          3          1                                 2                                 3                                                                                                                              
         2 foo          2          1                                 2                                                                                                                                                                
         3 foo          1          1                                                                                                                                                                                                  
         1 bar          1          1                                                                                                                                                                                                  
         2 bar          1          1
```

... and, finaly, mixing grid_pivot data with grid data using 6 left joins to fit 6 pairs of your data of interest into the grid.

```sql
SELECT    gp.ID, gp.GRP, 
          g1.COL_DATE "GRP_1_DATE", g1.COL_VALUE "GRP_1_VALUE",
          g2.COL_DATE "GRP_2_DATE", g2.COL_VALUE "GRP_2_VALUE",
          g3.COL_DATE "GRP_3_DATE", g3.COL_VALUE "GRP_3_VALUE",
          g4.COL_DATE "GRP_1_DATE", g4.COL_VALUE "GRP_4_VALUE",
          g5.COL_DATE "GRP_2_DATE", g5.COL_VALUE "GRP_5_VALUE",
          g6.COL_DATE "GRP_3_DATE", g6.COL_VALUE "GRP_6_VALUE"
        -- ...  ... ... ...
FROM      grid_pivot gp
LEFT JOIN grid g1 ON(g1.ID = gp.ID And g1.GRP = gp.GRP And g1.RN_GRP_ID = gp.GRP_1_LINK)
LEFT JOIN grid g2 ON(g2.ID = gp.ID And g2.GRP = gp.GRP And g2.RN_GRP_ID = gp.GRP_2_LINK)
LEFT JOIN grid g3 ON(g3.ID = gp.ID And g3.GRP = gp.GRP And g3.RN_GRP_ID = gp.GRP_3_LINK)
LEFT JOIN grid g4 ON(g4.ID = gp.ID And g4.GRP = gp.GRP And g4.RN_GRP_ID = gp.GRP_4_LINK)
LEFT JOIN grid g5 ON(g5.ID = gp.ID And g5.GRP = gp.GRP And g5.RN_GRP_ID = gp.GRP_5_LINK)
LEFT JOIN grid g6 ON(g6.ID = gp.ID And g6.GRP = gp.GRP And g6.RN_GRP_ID = gp.GRP_6_LINK)
--  ... ... ... ...
ORDER BY  gp.ROWS_TOT DESC, gp.GRP DESC, gp.ID ASC

R e s u l t :
        ID GRP GRP_1_DATE GRP_1_VALUE GRP_2_DATE GRP_2_VALUE GRP_3_DATE GRP_3_VALUE GRP_1_DATE GRP_4_VALUE GRP_2_DATE GRP_5_VALUE GRP_3_DATE GRP_6_VALUE
---------- --- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ---------- ----------- ---------- -----------
         1 foo 01-MAR-21          500 01-JUN-21         2000 01-JAN-21          100                                                                      
         2 foo 02-JAN-21          200 02-MAR-21          300                                                                                             
         3 foo 03-JAN-21          700                                                                                                                    
         1 bar 01-JUN-21         2000                                                                                                                    
         2 bar 02-JUN-21          400
```

Anyway you will probably need dynamic solution so, this could be interesting for something else, who knows what, when and where...